Postgres function subpath does not exist
I already install ltree extenstion in my postgres db using create extension ltree. In a table, I set column path using type ltree. But, when I run this query:
SELECT path FROM org WHERE path @> SUBPATH('ITDivision', 0, 1);
I got error:
[42883] ERROR: function subpath(unknown, integer, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

I use DataGrip. But, the same result got in dbeaver too. How solve it?

Try with double quote around ITDIVISION
